# Static vs Non Static

Tags: php

Estoy realizando unas prácticas de `MVC` en `PHP` y he visto que realizan una función de la siguiente manera:

```
    class EnlacesPaginas{

        public  function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel){

            if(($enlacesModel== "inicio") || ($enlacesModel== "nosotros") || ($enlacesModel== "servicios") || ($enlacesModel== "contactenos")){
                $modulo="Vistas/Modulos/".$enlacesModel.".php";
            }
            return $modulo;
        }
    }
```

Al realizar la misma función, me sale el siguiente *Warning*:

> Deprecated: Non-static method EnlacesPaginas::enlacesPaginasModel()
>   should not be called statically.

Al cambiar la función dicha por lo siguiente:

```
class EnlacesPaginas{

    public static function enlacesPaginasModel($enlacesModel){

        if(($enlacesModel== "inicio") || ($enlacesModel== "nosotros") || ($enlacesModel== "servicios") || ($enlacesModel== "contactenos")){
            $modulo="Vistas/Modulos/".$enlacesModel.".php";
        }
        return $modulo;

    }

}
```

Se soluciona el *Warning*.

Mi pregunta es la siguiente:  **¿Por qué ocurre este Warning?.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La diferencia esta en como llamas a tu metodo

Con la palabra `static` que hace que de la clase definida no sea necesario crear una instancia para acceder a sus propiedades o metodos

```
EnlacesPaginas::enlacesPaginasModel();
```

Sin la palabra `static`, osea que debes crear un objeto de esa clase para poder llamar a las funciones.

```
$var = new EnlacesPaginas();
$var->enlacesPaginasModel();
```

Comment: Entiendo!! gracias por explicarme la diferencia

Comment: De nada @Jesús, exito!